# Kotlin: Generics, reflection and the difference between type T and T:Any

Tags: generics, reflection, kotlin

If I try to access the javaClass of a generic type T the Kotlin compiler complains that T is not a subtype of kotlin.Any

```
class Foo<T> (val t: T ){
    val cls = t.javaClass // Error, T is not a subtype of kotlin.Any
}
```

If define T as a subtype of Any everything works ok.

```
class Bar<T:Any> (val t: T ){
    val cls = t.javaClass // OK
}
```

Q1) If type ´T´ is not a subtype of ´Any´ which class/classes can it be a subtype of ?

Q2) Do a javaClass exist for all instances of T and if so how do I access it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default [generic upper bound](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) is not `Any` but `Any?`.

This also implies that it's not null-safe to get a `javaClass` from a nullable argument.

To get a `javaClass` from a generic type instance with `Any?` upper bound, you can cast it to `Any`:

```
val cls = (t as Any).javaClass //unsafe
val clsOrNull = (t as? Any)?.javaClass //safe
```

Comment: One thing that puzzels me though is why I only need to cast for generic types. For a generic t `var clsOfT = t?.javaClass` this gives a compile error but for a regular type `var a : Any? = "A";  var clsOfA = a?.javaClass` this is ok even though both have the upperbound `:Any?` ?

Comment: @TomasKarlsson, +1, looks like a peculiarity of Kotlin generics. I'm going to find the answer.

Comment: Clarification to the above: `t` is a property of generic type `T`

Comment: @TomasKarlsson @hotkey it is known limitation due to lack of intersection types, namely `(T & Any)`. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10708