# What's the different of <reified T> with <reified T: Any> in Kotlin?

Tags: mockito, kotlin

The test class below, pass.

```
class SimpleClassTest {

    private inline fun <reified T> anyObject(): T {
        return Mockito.anyObject<T>()
    }

    lateinit var simpleObject: SimpleClass
    @Mock lateinit var injectedObject: InjectedClass


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun testSimpleFunction() {
        simpleObject = SimpleClass(injectedObject)
        simpleObject.simpleFunction()

        verify(injectedObject).settingDependentObject(anyObject())
    }
}
```

But if we change from

```
    private inline fun <reified T> anyObject(): T {
        return Mockito.anyObject<T>()
    }
```

to

```
    private inline fun <reified T: Any> anyObject(): T {
        return Mockito.anyObject<T>()
    }
```

It will fail with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mockito.anyObject<T>() must not be null
```

What's the different of `<reified T>` with `<reified T: Any>` in Kotlin?

**UPDATED**
With the answer that Any is non-null, then using `<reified T: Any>` shouldn't return error, since `settingDependentObject(...)` is declared receiving a non-null argument. I would expect `<reified T>` should error out instead, but it's opposite from what I understand.

Did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin: Generics, reflection and the difference between type T and T:Any](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602231/kotlin-generics-reflection-and-the-difference-between-type-t-and-tany)

Comment: Mockito.anyObject<T> is a java method and returns Platform-Type "Any!" That Type can be nullable or non-nullable. the kotlin-compiler won't infer anything there (because having null checks for every platform-type is noisy). so if you assign "Any!" to a "Any", this can fail at runtime. see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [stated in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) and [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35602699/155213) the default upper bound is `Any?`. In other words the following declarations are equivalent:

```
inline fun <reified T> anyObject(): T = Mockito.anyObject<T>()
inline fun <reified T:Any?> anyObject(): T = Mockito.anyObject<T>()
```

The `Mockito.anyObject<T>()` [will return `null`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/196ff979da156caa07e19f57e4849637d8bede1a/src/main/java/org/mockito/Matchers.java#L161) for both `T:Any` and `T:Any?`. When the method with return type `T:Any` is invoked the `null` value returned by Mockito fails the runtime check inserted by Kotlin compiler. The error you're getting is thrown before `settingDependentObject` is invoked.

Comment: Thanks meinsol. When the method with return type T:Any? is invoked, why doesn't the null value returned by Mockito fails the runtime check inserted by Kotlin compiler?

Comment: @Elye `T:Any?` can be `null`

Comment: Thanks @miensol. Understood now. A further question if you could answer... my `settingDependentObject` function is also not accepting null. When T:Any? returns Null, why doesn't `settingDependentObject` complaints?

Comment: @Eley As I mentioned in the answer the `IllegalStateException` is thrown before invoking `settingDependentObject`. The compiler doesn't complain when you have `settingDependentObject(anyObject())` and `<reified T:Any?> anyObject()` since `Any` _matches_ `T:Any?` but not vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

When you add `T : Any` constraint on a type parameter, you're making it effectively non-null: `T` is subtype of `Any` and `Any` can't hold nulls.

Since the function is inline and has a reified type parameter, that parameter gets substituted with a real non-nullable type. And thus a null-check is performed on a call site, so you're getting this exception.

Comment: Thanks llya. That helps explain the differences. I have some follow up question in the update, perhaps you could explain on?