# Why can't I get the class of a generic parameter?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a function which takes one argument of a generic type and I want to access the class of it:

```
fun <T> test(t: T) {
    t::class
}
```

This fails with "expression in class literal has nullable type". That's ok, I understand it (I could use `Any?` as my `T` and `null` as the value). 
But if I change it to guaranty that `t` is not-null it still fails with the same error message:

```
fun <T> test(t: T) {
    t!!::class
}
```

In which case can `t!!::class` still cause trouble? 
Is there a way to get the class without using Any (or casting to Any)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Change your type to indicate it is not-nullable and it should work. You can do this by indicating that `T` needs to extend `Any` (rather than `Any?`).

```
fun <T : Any> test(t: T) {
    t::class
}
```

Comment: ok, nice. But still, in which case can `t!!::class` be problematic?

Comment: Not really sure. I played with it and don't really have a good explanation, TBH.

Comment: @danielspaniol See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602231/kotlin-generics-reflection-and-the-difference-between-type-t-and-tany/35602699#35602699, the `t!!` is discussed in the comments of the answer.

Answer (score 11):

### First, let's fix it

Make the generic type `T` non-nullable:

```
fun <T: Any> test(t: T) {
    println(t::class)
}
```

By [default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html), the upper bound is `Any?` instead of `Any`:

> "The default upper bound (if none specified) is Any?. Only one upper bound can be specified inside the angle brackets. If the same type parameter needs more than one upper bound, we need a separate where-clause."

#### Side Note: You're using `!!` incorrectly

> "But if I change it to guaranty that t is not-null ..."

This is *not* what you're doing when using `!!`. Instead, you're telling the compiler: *I don't want you to check my type for nullability. Just go ahead and call that function. I'm not afraid of `NullpointerException`s.*

> "In which case can t!!::class still cause trouble?"

As I said above, it causes trouble when the type, which you invoke `!!` on, **is** `null`. Then, same as in Java, NPEs will be thrown at runtime.

Comment: I'd throwing a NPE in case of a null is what is wanted, because the null will most likely be a mistake, so I'd argue that this is exactly what would be wanted. Of course this expose the true problem, using nullable in the first place. The good thing about Kotlin is that is exposes the entry points of the nulls early on. Kotlin does not fix the underlying issues with nulls anyway, it only makes them nicer to work with.

Comment: I don't understand why the default upper bound is nullable - `Any?`, it would be simpler if it was just `Any`. It becomes rather inconvenient when there is a base class that is parameterized `Type<T : Any>` and then it's used to build subtypes - `SubType<Type<T : Any>>`. This approach makes it necessary to override the upper bound for every subclass.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the `reified` type. You can learn more about the reified type parameters [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) or [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/reified-type-parameters.md). The code:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> test(t: T) {
    println(T::class)
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do this. You can also pass the class to the function as he did

Comment: You're right. But I'm not sure, whether he wanted to get the class of that specific instance, or to get the the class from the type. Personally, I've never used `::class` function reference to access the entity's type.